# Instantiate PHP class without `new` keyword?

Tags: php

I am used to the `new` keyword, so I was surprised to find that the following works for instantiation as well.

```
class MyClass
{
    const CONSTANT = 'constant value';

    function showConstant() {
        echo  self::CONSTANT;
    }
}

// $classname = new MyClass;
$classname = "MyClass";

echo $classname::CONSTANT;
```

I can't seem to find any documentation pertaining to this online. Would someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

As of PHP 5.3.0, it's possible to reference the class using a variable [0]

You're not creating an instance of an object. So you're not instantiating a class. PHP constants can be access statically.

[0] http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php

Comment: I am still confused. I am sure there is somekind of instantiation going on... since I am accessing the `CONSTANT` in `MyClass`.

Comment: Wait... I think I get it. So `$classname` here is basically just another way of referring to the class `MyClass`... but like you said, there is no instantiation going on! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an instantiation, with the four dots (::) you can access an static variable, method or constant in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In fact `$classname` is just another way to say `MyClass`. So `$classname::CONSTANT` is the same as `MyClass::CONSTANT`. But there is not instantiation going on, as doing `$classname->showConstant()` would not work!!